# How to know the length in the Okhttp Response?

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

In my app I need to calculate the download speed. My problem is that the server is not returning the `Content-Length`. To calculate the length we were using `getBody().length()` from Retrofit Response, but this only works if logs are enabled, if I disable logs, then this value is `-1`. I'm trying to get the length adding an `Interceptor` but I have the same problem `response.body().contentLength()` is `-1`. Do you know how can I get the response length?

Thanks!

Comment: have you found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Your server isn't sending the length. There's no way to know without reading the entire doc.

Fortunately you don't need the length to compute download speed. Just take the net bytes returned divided by the time elapsed. 1 MiB in 4 seconds is 250 KiB per second.